# Making only picture clickable css/html inside header

Tags: html, css, image, center

I'm working on a responsive website and I'm having an annoying problem. In my header is some text. And I set it offscreen with text-indent -9999px. After that I load a background image. But I want only the background image to be clickable. I don't know how to do this. I've found a few examples on google. But they never "inject" a picture with css. They always define the picture in the html.

So all that I want is a picture horizontally centered in the header and only the picture is clickable, not the margin around it.

```
<header>
<a href="alink">
<h1>this is gonna be replaced with an image(on desktop websites). It will stay here on mobile website</h1></a>
</header>
```

and the css:

```
header h1 {
margin:10px 0 30px 0;
text-indent:-9999px;
background-image: url('pika.png');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: contain;
background-position:50% 50%;
width:100%;
height:220px;
border:1px solid red;
float: left;
}
```

I've also uploaded the code to jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/Cm3yQ/

As you can see, currently the whole h1 is clickable, and I want only the picture to be clickable.

Comment: I don't think there is any simple solution, another related question here is *What if you have an image of a dragon instead of that pikachu?* and even a much more complicated image? You may have to **manually** build the maps for the important points in the image and use `ismap` or `usemap` attribute (for anchors), that means you have to rebuild the maps if the image is changed.

Comment: You've styled your `h1` to be 100% width by 220px height and, therefore, that's what's "clickable." If you only want the header to be as wide/tall as your background image, than change the width & height accordingly.

Comment: But if I set it to less than 100%, it isn't centered on my screen anymore. It goes to the left side of my screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<edit>`

Possibilities to have only image clikable are:

1. the use of `img` + `map` + `area`
2. or the use of `SVG`. one random tutorial : http://tutorials.jenkov.com/svg/a-element.html
   Average example of what can be done : **[DEMO](http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/nFzjL/)**

`</edit>`

---

You should wrap link inside `h1`, and give it a `display:block`.

```
header {
  background:url(http://lorempixel.com/400/150);
  /* background could either be on h1 or a */
  background-size:cover;/* optionnal */
}
header, h1 , h1 a  {/* size them all at once */
  display:block;
  height:300px;
}
a {
  text-indent:-9999px;/* hide text from screen */
  /* still not working ? set background here or give it a color 
  almost transparent so it can catch click event : 
  background:rgba(0,0,0,0.001);*/
}
```

and HTML :

```
<header>
  <h1>
    <a href="#"> SOME text </a>
  </h1>
</header>
```

Comment: But I want a small image in the center of the header, is this possible with your example? because now i have again a header that is entirely clickable.

Comment: sorry , i missed the part where you only want the image clickable.

Comment: For what you want you need to use SVG, anyhow, image has to be in HTML. The most commun way to do this is to use a <map> and <area>

Comment: I have the file as an psd photoshop format. Can I export that to an svg and will everything work then?

Comment: A bit more complexe, you need to set the clickable area and give it a xlink too. i'll look for an english tutorial

Comment: I'll have to look. But I was thinking. If I'm able to horizontally center this: http://jsfiddle.net/qtHPJ/ , Won't that be an easier fix?

Comment: yes of course , but if you really want only picachu to be clicked , SVG can allow you to set an area all around it . hand made example : http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/nFzjL/ , shape (path) has to set, then filled with your image :)

Comment: The shape you cut out, how can I make it, to be a circle? I think it's omewhere in path. But I'm not sure :p

Comment: nop, i updated the pen : http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/nFzjL/ replace path with circle

Comment: yeah just saw my fault ;) thanks alot. Can I still set the image destination with css?

Comment: stroke and fill can be set in css style sheet

Comment: yeah. Because the image only needs to appear when I'm on a desktop not on a smartphone.

Comment: yep , see this example http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/Dqcio where fill and stroke are set in css it even overwrites value set inline

Answer (score 1):

it may look like a comment but i dont have enough reputations to put comment ,hence am putting it as an answer.

Why dont you create another div in the html and put your image inside it ,then style it accordingly.

Comment: So why don't you try editing the fiddle posted by the OP and post that in your answer?

Answer (score 1):

HTML

```
<header>
<div class="headerDiv">
    <a href="anotherfile"><h1>this is gonna be replaced with an image(on desktop website). It will stay here on mobile website</h1></a>
</div>
</header>
```

Css

```
.headerDiv{
 border:1px solid red;
 height:220px;
 width:100%;    
}

header h1 {
 margin:10px 0 30px 0;
 text-indent:-9999px;
 background-image:      url('http://img3.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20120630141813/sims/images/d/d7/Pichu.gif');
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: contain;
 background-position:center; 

 height:220px;
 // float: left;    Get Rid of float: left
}
```

Comment: But now the entire header is clickable again?